# Weird Hibernate SerializationException that only occurs in my own computer

Tags: java, hibernate

I got a weird exception on with hibernate.
***Attention! I run complete same code from git which runs in our QA test environment. And all my colleagues local environment also works with the same code!***

the following is the code , it's just a simple query.

```
List<BaseOrderItem> list = em.createQuery("select o from BaseOrderItem o where o.status=:status and o.orderTypeDivision=:orderType")
    .setParameter("status", OrderItemSatus.WAIT_FOR_APPROVAL)
    .setParameter("orderType", OrderTypeDivision.CHE)
    .setFirstResult(page * PAGE_SIZE)
    .setMaxResults(PAGE_SIZE)
    .getResultList();
```

I'm sure that the problem must not comes from the code, cause all the other environment(QA server and colleagues local computer) runs the same code, and they works fine.
**And all querys created by hibernate got the same Exception in my local computer.**

I believe there must be something wrong with my local computer.
Besides, my Computer is MAC Pro 2017.

The following is the stacktrace:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:492)
at com.labnetwork.services.orders.impl.OrderRequisitionService.getWaitForApproveOrder(OrderRequisitionService.java:95)
at com.labnetwork.services.orders.impl.OrderRequisitionService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7546a4b2.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
at com.labnetwork.services.orders.impl.OrderRequisitionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8078f2e.getWaitForApproveOrder(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:458)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:289)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:262)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:178)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProducer.process(BeanProducer.java:41)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.doService(CamelServlet.java:195)
at org.apache.camel.http.common.CamelServlet.service(CamelServlet.java:74)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:27)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2738)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.loadFromResultSet(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:306)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.hydrateEntityState(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:233)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:103)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:239)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:122)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3967)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.returnNarrowedProxy(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:310)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:270)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:639)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:154)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:128)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1133)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:992)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
... 80 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: EFBFBDEF
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:862)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:354)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299)
at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218)
... 128 common frames omitted
```

The BaseOrderItem .

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_items")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "item_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class BaseOrderItem extends BasePersistable {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
private Product product;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product_package_id")
private ProductPackage originalPackage;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "life_science_id")
private LifeScienceProduct lifeScienceProduct;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "lab_consumable_id")
private LabConsumable labConsumable;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "bioreagent_id")
private Bioreagent bioreagent;

//Price and currency can be null for people shopping in countries where no
//price is defined.
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "currency_id")
private Currency currency;
private BigDecimal unitPrice;
//If the currency the user is shopping in is different then the suppliers
//currency we want to save their price at time of order creation.
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "supplier_currency_id")
private Currency supplierUnitCurrency;
private BigDecimal supplierUnitPrice;

/**
 * Used for items that are priced from a table, where quantity determines
 * the total price and not individual unitPrice.
 */
private BigDecimal totalPrice;
private boolean priceOverridden = false;
@NotNull
private Long quantity;
@NotNull
private String unit;
@NotNull
private BigDecimal unitSize;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
private Country country;
private String itemNumber;
private String internalItemNumber;
private BigDecimal labNetworkCost;
private String labNetworkCostCurrencyCode;
private String labNetworkCostCurrencySymbol;
private String unitDescription;

private boolean internalOrderItem = false;

@Column(name = "quote_response_id")
private Integer quoteResponseId;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "quote_response_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private QuoteSupplierResponse quoteResponse;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "order_items_discounts",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_item_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "discount_id"))
private List<Discount> discounts = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany()
@JoinTable(name = "order_item_inventory",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_item_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_inventory_id"))
private List<ProductInventory> inventory = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinTable(name = "order_item_mk_inventory",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_items_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "mk_inventory_id"))
private List<MkInventory> mkInventories = new ArrayList<>();

private String status;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private OrderTypeDivision orderTypeDivision;

private Integer shipTime;

@Column(name = "quote_response_package_id")
private Long quoteResponsePackageId;

private Boolean lnQcEnable;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private QuoteCategory quoteCategory;

@OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinTable(name = "order_item_external_product",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "orderItemId"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "externalProductId"))
private ExternalProducts externalProducts;

private Integer supplierCompanyId;
private String productName;
private String productNameCn;
private String supplierProductId;
private String cas;
private String mdl;
private String purity;
}
```

Comment: can you provide `BaseOrderItem` code ?

Comment: @benjaminc BaseOrderItem is added